# Rails 5: Error when removed quiet_assets_path from development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been trying to upgrade my app from Rails 4 to Rails 5. In my Rails 4 version I have quiet_assets_path set but in Rails 5 it is not required. But when I removed that tried to start the server I am getting the following error,

```
> ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.2/lib/mini_profiler_rails/railtie.rb:93:in
> `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)     from
> /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.2/lib/mini_profiler_rails/railtie.rb:93:in
> `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

Can someone help me with this?

**Edit:**

Following is my rack_profiler.rb,

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
  require 'rack-mini-profiler'

  # initialization is skipped so trigger it
  Rack::MiniProfilerRails.initialize!(Rails.application)
  Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_schema_queries = true
  Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths += %w(/admin/sidekiq)

  Rails.application.middleware.delete(Rack::MiniProfiler)
  Rails.application.middleware.insert_after(Rack::Deflater, Rack::MiniProfiler)
end
```

When I comment the delete line then server is starting but if the line uncommented then the server breaks.

Comment: Are you sure that Rack::MiniProfiler is still in your middleware stack? [This](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/lib/mini_profiler_rails/railtie.rb#L93) is your error. I guess the gem monkey patches some middleware, probably `Rails::Rack::Logger`.

Comment: please check edit

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the update. First of all, do you use `Rack::Deflater` middleware in `development` environment too?

I think this [issue](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/issues/242) might help you. It basically says that in Rails all [delete middleware operations are issued at the end](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a39498ae060f07132ddbbc45933a819686f0eb24). You can use the `swap` method as described in the above issue.

If you search the repo issues for "Deflater" you'll find a lot of results, but I believe the above contains your fix.